# How parser Linux input/output ASCII with control chart to finally string, use golang or python or shell

Tags: python, shell, go, terminal, ascii

I got a hex ASCII charts A and has many control charts in A, like this

```
A = 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
```

And I exec command

```
echo "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" |python -c "s = raw_input().decode('hex'); print(str(s))"

(reverse-i-search)`ls': ls /opt/
```

I get the result "(reverse-i-search)`ls': ls /opt/", but there are many control charts in the result. When I exec like this

```
echo "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" |python -c "s = raw_input().decode('hex'); print(str(s))" | python -c "print(raw_input().encode('hex'))"

0d1b5b374028726576657273652d692d7365617263682960273a1b5b430808086c273a206c73202f6f70742f7372632f70662d72696e672d746573742f746573742e676f0d1b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b430808081b5b3140731b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b43200d1b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b431b5b4b08081b5b431b5b43202f6f70742f0808080808080808
```

The result is the same as A.

How can I get the real string "(reverse-i-search)`ls': ls /opt/" that doesn't contain control ASCII chart from the ASCII charts A, like this

```
echo -e "(reverse-i-search)\`ls': ls /opt/" |  python -c "print(raw_input().encode('hex'))"

28726576657273652d692d73656172636829606c73273a206c73202f6f70742f
```

Comment: The encoded string is full of garbage: https://play.golang.org/p/bm9Mn1CiFIf, are you sure your input is correct and that it's meant to be a plain string? If it is correct, it looks more like the raw terminal output of a shell session.

Comment: Yeah, this is a raw terminal output string, and I want to parser the string and split the real command "ls /opt/", which input enter will be exec.

Comment: You might need to explain the problem. This output is meant for human eyes, not programs. It's the "callback command history" feature of the shell.

Comment: U meant get the command from the "command history" of the shell? I want to get the command before the command be executing, not the history command list. I want to get the command and judge it is the dangerous command like "rm" or "kill", and I will reject it in my ssh proxy service.

Comment: You're solving the problem in the wrong place, SSH sends characters one by one, it'll be almost impossible to cover all cases of someone doing something nasty. Instead, you should be restricting what the user can do on the server itself.